# asterisk sip extension to receive sip call from anyone having my sip address

Tags: asterisk

I need a sip extension to receive sip call from anyone who have my sip address.

e.g. if anyone calls 101@xyz.com then sip call should drop on 101 extension configured in a soft phone, where xyz.com can be considered as my asterisk server IP address.

Help me. I am new to asterisk server.

Please provide me a step wise step guide to achieve the goal.

I got success in setting up sip extension that work in local network now I want to set sip extension which capable to receive incoming sip call from anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Request to all valuable member: Please before vote down let me know where I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You have set in sip.conf in general section

```
allowguest=yes
context=strangers
```

After that you can define in extensions.conf context strangers which have determine where to calls.